# How to inset <script> into div in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Maybe someone came across such a problem and can suggest how to solve it:
I need to insert the script into a special div. And this script changes the DOM. Insets block, adds classes and styles. It is external script and
it renders this page.
There is no problem in Vue. then Nuxt throws errors.
can someone suggest what to do about it?)

error:

> nuxt-error.vue?48f2:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'accept' of undefined
> at eval (VM6157 nuxt-error.vue:14)
> at Object../node_modules/vue-style-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./.nuxt/components/nuxt-error.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
> (app.js:437)
> at a (app.js:2)
> at eval (VM6156 nuxt-error.vue:2)
> at Module../.nuxt/components/nuxt-error.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
> (app.js:119)
> at a (app.js:2)
> at eval (VM6151 nuxt-error.vue:4)
> at Module../.nuxt/components/nuxt-error.vue (app.js:95)
> at a (app.js:2)
> at eval (VM6142 index.js:35)

```html
<template>
    <div class="skin" ref="scriptHolder">
      <div id="hwm-ubs-ticketsystem" data-id="757d440c95b9539fd9f79b8407fb8e9fe23b23315cfe6085">      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  components: {
  },
  mounted() {
    let scriptEl = document.createElement('script')
    scriptEl.src = 'https://site/assets/js/app.js'
    scriptEl.type = "text/javascript"
    let styleEl = document.createElement('link')
    styleEl.setAttribute('href', 'https://site/assets/css/app.css')
    styleEl.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet')
    const divEl = document.querySelector('#hwm-ubs-ticketsystem')
    this.$refs['scriptHolder'].insertBefore(styleEl, divEl)
    this.$refs['scriptHolder'].appendChild(scriptEl)
  }

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oatEB.png)

Comment: When do you want to execute this script? When the page renders or on click?

Comment: When the page renders

Comment: If you want to add a class for example you could just use v-bind and add a class when the page renders

Comment: For that you just need to define a Boolean in data() for example pageLoaded: false, I think this page explains it better https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: Yes, but it is external script and I can't edit it. All actions on this page must be performed by this script. All classes and styles adds by external script too. It render content this page

Comment: That’s tricky. It depends on what you script does and when it’s doing it. If, for example, you’re adding a script that starts when the DOMContentLoaded event is triggered, that event would have already been triggered before mounted(), thus your script will not get executed.

Comment: But there is no problem in Vue. It looks like this is a Nuxt problem.

Comment: As if there is a problem of updating styles in Nuxt. But maybe i'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can check if problem is with webpackJson default name. Nuxt uses webpack 4 version and maybe your external script uses webpack 4 also, so webpackJson is populated by nuxt first and then with external script and there is a conflict when running so you can change default name for you nuxt project with jsonpFunction: 'webpackJsonp_name', and then your external script should load webpackJson default.